# how specify jquery chosen selected items placeholder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-chosen

I need to place choices below select control. So i want to override default behavior when control puts seleced items into this select control

[image: example control]

Is it possible to do using [jquery-chosen](/questions/tagged/jquery-chosen) or I need to use other jquery plugins for this purposes?

Comment: are you looking for [<select>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Zmf6t/1135/

Comment: Probably you should choose another plugin ;), there is no easy way to remove selected tags programmatically. This is all I could do about it, dunno how to continue: http://jsfiddle.net/Zmf6t/1136/ I hope that somebody else will help you better.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
<select id="test" name="test" class="chosen" multiple="multiple">
    <option selected value="val1">Item 1</option>//Selected Value
    <option selected value="val2">Item 2</option>//Selected Value
    <option value="val3">Item 3</option>//Unselected Value
</select>
```

Chosen is a plugin to give it the look and feel. Its basically html select only.

Cheers.